# How to design a jQuery progress bar from the scratch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to design a jQuery progress bar which progresses with user input .
I tried several codes but they are not working and when I load the page it is totally blank.
please help me through . Am I missing a trick here ?
Do I have to download all the .js files 
and if so how to download them ?
Please help me with a detailed tutorial how to design a progress bar s I am quite new to JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryui1.7/development-bundle/themes/smoothness/ui.core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryui1.7/development-bundle/themes/smoothness/ui.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryui1.7/development-bundle/themes/smoothness/ui.progressbar.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui1.7/development-bundle/jquery-1.3.2.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui1.7/development-bundle/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui1.7/development-bundle/ui/ui.progressbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

        //call progress bar constructor           
        $("#container").progressbar({ value: 50 });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "How to download them": https://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: Learn how to deal with External JavaScripts first, then learn to look for errors is browser Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `progressbar` is a function of `jQuery UI` so you have to include them too

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Progress Bar</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery UI -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
  //call progress bar constructor           
    $("#container").progressbar({ value: 50 });
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's better if you don't download the jQuery framework, but you use the one hosted by Google

Comment: I copy and pasted the whole code but again when I load the page in the browser it is blank. Why is it?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Progress bar in HTML is made from two elements, one inside other one.

```
<div class="progress-bar">
    <div style="width: 60%"></div>
</div>
```

With CSS by default, you give outer container specific width, height and border, for inner container, you give maximum height and some background color.

```
.progress-bar {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.progress-bar > div {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0F0;
}
```

And now, you only need to change width of inner container with JavaScript (jQuery), to change/show progress of yours.

```
$('.progress-bar > div').css('width', '75%');
```

That is it. You don't need any fancy libraries for any of this, in fact, you can change that width without jQuery, if you like.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar > div')[0].style.width = '75%';
```

Here is a demo code http://jsfiddle.net/Deele/7Wmju/

PS: HTML5 even has built-in progress bar, that can be manipulated, to suit ones needs. Read about it http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/